# Login fails when using webrat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, redirect, restful-authentication, webrat

I am using restful_authentication 1.1.6  on rails 2.3.5 and testing with webrat 0.7.1
The login works fine when I use a browser to test it. When
I use webrat, it first correctly logs in and sets the current_user and session[:user_id].
Then, when  performing the redirect at the end of the action (:controller => session, :action => create), it sets the session[:user_id] and current_user to nil!
This happens only when there is a redirect at the end. If there is a “render :text”, then the values of session[:user_id] and current_user will not be erased!
Any ideas, how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I froze wrong version of rails (2.3.8). Everything works fine after I froze version 2.3.5.